# send payment to one or more customers via flask script or third party website

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

Still new in python.  I am trying to creating an e-commerce website where tutors can sell their online courses and e-books, using Flask. Now I am faced with new challenge. How can I send payment to multiple customers all at once? Can I create a script using flask to send payment? is there any third party platform I can use for such purpose ? Is it a good idea to save user's bank account details in database? please, I need your reply.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving *any* of these issues yourself?

Comment: accepting payment from stripe I have done successfully (although test mode) but I have no idea how to send to one or more customer's bank account from website

Comment: @mama you mean python api can handle this? which of the api ?

Comment: "Can I create a script using flask to send payment?".  -yes

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

You need to a) accept money b) send money. Those are not flask questions or python questions.

You need a service (like Stripe) that is set up to accept payments and send payments and you need your flask app to connect to that service and provide the necessary instructions using their API.

Checkout Stripe Connect as a product that does this. https://stripe.com/gb/connect